# Add prev & next li's to pagination function

Tags: javascript

I want to add prev and next li's to my pagination function. The function itself works perfectly and shows the amount of pages by the amount of rows you want to view received from a dropdown .val();

```
function pagination() {
    $('table[data-provide=pagination]').each(function () {

        var $table = $('#foo');
        var $pager = $('<ul></ul>');

        var currentPage = 0;
        var numPerPage = $("#bar").val();
        var numRows = $table.find('.someclass').length;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);

        $table.unbind('repaginate');

        $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
            $table.find('.someclass').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        });

        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
            var link = '<a href="#">' + page + '</a>';

            $('<li></li>').html(link).on('click', {
                newPage: page
            }, function (event) {
                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }).appendTo($pager);
        };

        var prev = '<li id="pagiprev"><a href="#' + (currentPage - 1) + '">&laquo</a></li>';
        var next = '<li id="paginext"><a href="#' + (currentPage + 1) + '">&raquo</a></li>';

        $pager.append(next);
        $pager.prepend(prev);

        $pager.find("li:first-child").addClass('active');

        $($table.data('pager')).html($pager);
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
    });
};
```

Now Ive added:

```
var prev = '<li id="pagiprev"><a href="#' + (currentPage - 1) + '">&laquo</a></li>';
var next = '<li id="paginext"><a href="#' + (currentPage + 1) + '">&raquo</a></li>';

$pager.append(next);
$pager.prepend(prev);
```

But apparently it is not that easy as I thought. Of course making the next and prev li's work so it jumps to the next of prev page is step 1. It should also add or remove the 'active' class based on the last or first page as it does not make sense to be able to click on the prev button if you are on the first page.

Comment: A bit of your markup would be nice... (and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))

Comment: Meh, its kinda hard to give you markup as my table is build by ajax. I can see what i can do to get a working fiddle.